# Apex controller method is not getting invoked in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, action

getSendList method is not getting invoked in controller

```
<apex:page controller="sampleController" action="{!getSendList}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="PDF" applyHtmlTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" readOnly="true">

<head>
    <!-- CUSTOM STYLES -->
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: "Salesforce Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 1.5;
        }

        @page {
            @top-center {
                content: element(header);
            }
            @bottom-center {
                content: element(footer);
            }
            margin-top: 180px;
            margin-bottom: 165px;
        }
        .pagenumber:before {
            content: counter(page);
        }
        .pagecount:before {
            content: counter(pages);
        }
        .header span {
            font-size: 24px;
        }
        div.header {
            padding-top: 50px; position: running(header);
        }
        div.footer {
            display: block; padding-bottom: 200px; position: running(footer); font-size: small;
        }
        table.il {
            font-size: 70%; border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .il th {
            border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;
        }
        .il td {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .il tbody {
            font-size: 82.5%;
        }
        table.tg {
            margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 85%; border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .tg th {
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .tg th, .tg td {
            font-size: 57.5%;
        }
        table.tg, .tg th, .tg td {
            border: 1px solid #cac9d9;
        }
        p.tg, .tg li  {
            text-color: #333333; font-size: 73%;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- /CUSTOM STYLES -->
</head>
<h>test</h>
<apex:repeat value="{!userList}" var="check">

    {!check.checkNumber}
</apex:repeat>
```

Controller method

```
public PageReference getSendList() {

    this.userList = new List<DME_WrapperCheck>();

    for(DME_WrapperCheck wc : checkItemList) {
         userList.add(wc);
    }

    System.debug('tempCheckItemList');

    this.setup = new DME_Setup__c();
    this.setup = DME_SharedMethods.getDMESetup();

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_methods.htm), getter methods have the name get*Variable*. These are then referenced from the page via *variable*. Try changing your page to use:

```
action="{!sendList}"
```

Comment: There was another issue.Thanks

Comment: Please add an answer for your own question so people finding this question at a later date know what the solution was.